# Applescript Javascript Music Radio Station

Tags: applescript, javascript

I am trying to get working in my AppleScript to show me the artist and name of song from the radio station that is playing. the code I have now works for regular music but just not the radio stations. Any ideas?

```
if (Application("Music").running()) {
  const track = Application("Music").currentTrack;
}
```

For the radio the terminal just shows me `[object Application]`. So not sure what I am missing

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different! This is JS, not AppleScript, right...? What API are you using for this? Is there a reason this question is better suited for Ask Different than Stack Overflow?

Comment: This is applescript

Comment: This doesn’t look like any AppleScript I know... how are you ruining it?

Comment: osascript -l javascript ./tunes.js

Comment: Gotcha, sorry for the confusion. I think the preferred term is JavaScript for Automation (JXA); sorry I didn’t quite get that at first.